# Watermark text to fill the text area

Tags: tcolorbox, backgrounds, watermark, wallpaper

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[table]{standalone}
\usepackage{lipsum, graphicx, polyglossia, enumitem, amssymb, pifont, booktabs, cancel, animate, ulem, ragged2e}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\linespread{2}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
  enhanced,
  before upper=\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount},
  colframe=black,
  boxrule=2mm,
  bottomrule=8mm,
  colbacktitle=black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\centering,
  coltitle=white,
  colback=yellow!10!white,
  coltext=black,
  finish={\node[rotate=45, fill opacity=0.25, inner sep=5mm] at (frame.center) {\Huge\bfseries Watermark Text!};
  \node[white, font=\footnotesize, anchor=south, text width=.95\textwidth] at (frame.south) {\hfill Hello World};},
  title=#2,#1}

\newcommand{\xxbody}{
  \lipsum[2,4]
  \noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}\qquad
  \lipsum[2,4]
}

\newcommand{\xxheading}{%
  Heading
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{\LARGE \xxheading{}}

  \xxbody{}

\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

How do I get multiple copies of the 'Watermark Text!' to cover the entire text area (i.e. it does not spill onto the borders)?

But at the same time, the 'Watermark Text!' needs to be above the image.

Also, how do automatically set the height of the bottom border so that 'Hello World' appears properly centered in it?

Or at least, get 'Hellor World' to be vertically centrally aligned?